# CrossTable function in other formatting

Tags: r, xtable

Is there a way to transform the table output created with the Crosstable function into another format?

I tried using xtable

```
library(gmodels)

library(descr)

TB14.4 =CrossTable(AvaliacaoEAD,instrucao,prop.r=TRUE, prop.c=TRUE,
                   prop.t=FALSE, prop.chisq=FALSE, format="SPSS" )

install.packages("xtable")
library(xtable)

xtable(TB14.4)
```

The error was as follows:

```
Error in UseMethod ("xtable"):
   method not applicable for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "list"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CrossTable` object produced by `descr` package is more flexible, whether you are trying to store the `CrossTable` output or the content of the calculations. For example, this R Markdown document:

````
---
title: "CrossTable Example"
output: html_document
---
<style>
.main-container {
    max-width: 940px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
}
</style>

```{r example, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(descr)
library(pander)
my.table <- descr::CrossTable(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$mpg, prop.r=TRUE, prop.c=TRUE, prop.t=FALSE, prop.chisq=FALSE, format="SPSS")
class(my.table)
pander(my.table)
```
````

Produces an object of type `CrossTable` that is easily formatted by `pander` even for large numbers of columns. Note that you can choose at this point to make it easier to read by setting one or more of the `prop` to `FALSE`.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! It worked, thank you very much!

Is there a way to put the title and font in this package?

Comment: Yes, you can customize all the fonts in R Markdown (see https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_quick_tour.html). If this helped you solve the problem, could you check to accept the answer? Thanks... glad it is useful for you.